# Swift Can not find Class (typedef struct objc_class *Class)?

Tags: objective-c, swift, class

This is my written in Objective-C code, now I want to put it into a Swift code. But I found that Swift and there is no Class modifier, its AnyClass, is not what I need, what should I do?

```
+ (void)postJson:(ZYHttpRequest *)httpRequest resultClass:(Class)resultClass success:(void (^)(ZYBaseResult *result))success failure:(void (^)(NSError *error))failure
{
     [self postJsonWithProgressHint:nil httpRequest:httpRequest resultClass:resultClass success:success failure:failure];
}
```

Typedef struct objc_class * ClassUse "Class" in the Objective-C can bearing type, but how to write in the Swift?

The above code, written in a Swift, how do I correct writing "resultClass:(Class)resultClass"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
func postJson<T: AnyObject>(httpRequest: ZYHttpRequest, resultClass:T.Type, ...
```

Comment: why not just use `AnyClass` (which is `AnyObject.Type`)?

Comment: Cause it will throw error when you call the function.